# Porque no se cambia el valor de la variable global en PHP

Tags: php, array

En mi código dispongo de un array global que se utiliza en dos funciones añadir y listar, primero siempre se ejecuta añadir, para añadir algún elemento al array y utilizo listar para devolver el array.
El problema es que tras añadir, el listar tiene una comprobación para ver el tamaño del array pero este siempre me figura como vacío, a que se puede deber esto?, por qué no se está añadiendo correctamente con el array_push?

Adjunto el código

```
<?php

$listaCarrito = array();

class SAProducto {

public static function anadirProductoCarroSA($nombre){
        global $listaCarrito;
        array_push($listaCarrito, $nombre);
    }
    
    public static function listarProductosCarroSA(){
        global $listaCarrito;
        $numero = sizeof($listaCarrito);
        echo"$numero";
        if($numero == 0){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            return $listaCarrito;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque `$listaCarrito` está vacío y no tiene nada que añadir, prueba así y, por supuesto, instanciando la clase:

```
$listaCarrito = [
    1,2,3
];

$s = new SAProducto();
$s->anadirProductoCarroSA(4);
$s->anadirProductoCarroSA(5);
print_r($s->listarProductosCarroSA());
```